# Client app able to call API Locally but unable to do it in IIS

Tags: .net-core

I have an application that his a .Net Core API.

Everything works locally, and by that means,

```
Client App --> hits an .Net Core API successfully.
```

Howevever we have pushed the app to IIS Server, and we are not able to successfuly hit the API.

I know this is extremely vague, but what is something that I should be looking at to diagnose address this. I pulled the code from the published branch, and it works like a charm on local, but does not work on Server.

I do not get any Server Side exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there network connectivity? Log into the server and open a browser and put in the URL to the API. Any HTTP error is good. It means you can reach the API. If it times out, that's bad and that's your problem.

How do you know there are no exceptions? Are you logging all exceptions? Are you sure no exceptions are hidden in `try` blocks that end up ignoring the exception?

Assuming it's a Windows server, check the Event Viewer for warnings or errors.